# Woodland outdoor microscopy advice

Tags: microscopy

Let me start by saying I have never used a microscope outdoors, and in general I have never owned a microscope nor used one regularly.

However, I am currently developing and organising some activities for children, to be carried out in a woodland. I thought it would be really interesting to use a microscope to analyse and compare different samples: leaves, insects, etc. In a word, to do some "field microscopy" (I googled that, but doesn't seem to be a popular expression).

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it easy?
3. What type of microscope should I look for? We have quite a bit of funding, so feel free to suggest anything.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Worth considering DSLR and Macro lens. Take a look at [macro photography](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=macro+photography&newwindow=1&safe=off&biw=1366&bih=645&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMImbb7x5-PyQIVR1aOCh1vhQp0) samples. Advantage over microscope is that it is way easy to handle outdoors.

Comment: Use of pocket microscopes is not only professional; it is [antique](http://www.antique-microscopes.com/photos/browning.htm) enough.

Answer (score 4):

1: Yes it is possible

2: It's not as easy as lab conditions because of variable conditions, chances of equipment breaking, especially when small children are involved.

3: You can also look at a [Foldscope](http://www.foldscope.com/). Its a small, but powerful microscope made with paper. It was developed by a scientist called Manu Prakash, and although it is still in its beta testing stage, I'm sure you would be able to obtain a few for your students. It is incredibly cheap, very customizable and really user friendly.

P.S.: With the amount I endorse the Foldscope, you would have thought they could have shipped one of the damn things to India for me.

Comment: Wow nice information about foldscope.

Answer (score 2):

You could go wild in a forest with a microscope if you had batteries.

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. 200X

Answer (score 2):

There are a range of "nature microscopes" you can buy that will do this.

One cool new portable microscope with video storage is the [Mustcam](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Y0BE164).

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to (have the children) construct some *[pooters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirator_(entomology))* (with a clear vessel to allow viewing) to catch small insects with and use magnifying glasses or hand lenses [like this one which gives a range of magnifications.](http://www.acornnaturalists.com/store/5x10x15x-FOLDING-POCKET-LOUPE-P5814C47.aspx)

For most of the things you would want to look at you would not need massive magnification (i.e. you wouldn't need a scope). Microscopes also give the issue of how to fix the object (if it's a living mobile thing) to immobilise it, and a magnifying lens is generally more portable and affordable.

A good tip for looking at very small things up close in the field is to look at them the with binoculars but using the binoculars backwards - it allows you to get a good close view.

Answer (score 2):

IMO you don't need more than 20-40x for bugs and leaves. Beyond that it gets hard to find and focus on the sample, and the optics have more obvious aberrations.

"Field microscope" is a good category to look for. You need a light source in the scope -- most have a small LED. I got a couple of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KAS587W) for my 6- and 8-year-old kids and they have surprisingly good optical quality and durability. I linked to Amazon because there is a sample photo in the reviews.  I'm a professional microscopist, so I'm picky about these things, but I was impressed.

With the field scope I mentioned you can pull off the stage (part that holds a slide) and just hold the scope up to the side of a tree or a rock. Super cool.

Also, look for some rotten wood, or an acorn with a hole in it, and break it up to find the insect larvae inside.